# Seperate a range into single line adding the values in between

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a text list with values in a range as follows:

```
TSNN-00500--00503 TSNN-00510--00515
```

But I need to separate them into single lines in a text file and add the values in between.

Can this be done with a script easily?

Want the result in a new text file as follow

```
TSNN-00500
TSNN-00501
TSNN-00502
TSNN-00503
TSNN-00510
TSNN-00511
TSNN-00512
TSNN-00513
TSNN-00514
TSNN-00515
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

*easy way* is subjective.

Getting a sequence from a range can be performed with `seq`:

```
$ seq -f%05.0f 00500 00503
00500
00501
00502
00503
```

Getting the range from the string you provide can be performed with bash find-and-replace:

```
$ text='TSNN-00500--00503'
$ echo ${text//[^0-9]/ }
00500 00503
```

Prepending a string to a line can be performed with `sed`:

```
$ echo 00502 | sed 's/^/TSNN-/'
TSNN-00502
```

Wrapping everything in a loop gives:

```
$ for i in TSNN-00500--00503 TSNN-00510--00515 ; do seq -f%05.0f ${i//[^0-9]/ } | sed 's/^/TSNN-/' ; done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will try it also. Easy is subjective but the answers is easy enough, well explained, for me to understand. Very grateful.